# Is there a case made for the [transitive-closure] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I noticed that we have a tag for [transitive-closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive-closure), which seems to me as somewhat redundant. Here are two arguments I have in mind.

Firstly, it's unclear if we are talking about the general relational term, or just the specific set theoretic construction of a transitive set containing a given set.

Secondly, in the former (and likely) case, this should be just subsumed under [relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relations), rather than existing on its own. There's little to no specialization in this tag that would require it to be separate.

---

Should this tag be removed? become a synonym of one of the relation-related tags? or perhaps I'm wrong, and there is a case for it being left on the site?

Comment: I think it should be removed.  I can't think of any current tag for which this could a synonym.  I agree this should be subsumed under the "relations" tag.

Comment: Transitive closure is a pretty important construction, not only in connection with ordinals, but in algorithms for graphs.  It would seem to be an important sub-topic in relations.  I'll do some queries to see if this is at all represented in its actual use.

Comment: @hardmath: And functions are arguably the most important object in mathematics, nevertheless the [functions] tag is not a good one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll call this a consensus. [transitive-closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) has been merged into [relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relations) and is no more.

Comment: It seems like there should be some joke here about [(transitive-closure)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) becoming a victim of closure, but I can't quite make it ….